# How to modify the elements of one list based on another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists like

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
lst2 = ['q', 'r', 's']
```

Now, suppose I generate a mapping from list2 to list1 one like (4, 0, 3) meaning update the 4th element of list1 with the 0th element of list2, update the 0th element of list1 with the 1st element of list2, etc. such that the resulting list looks like

```
lst1 = ['r', 'b', 'c', 's', 'q']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: `list2[4,0,3] = list1` and `list2[(4,0,3)] = list1`  (Both are obviously wrong.  No need to explain why.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
lst2 = ['q', 'r', 's']
mapping = [4, 0, 3]

for lst2_n, lst1_n in enumerate(mapping):
    lst1[lst1_n] = lst2[lst2_n]
```